# Regex one or two specific letters

Tags: java, regex

My correct expression is:

-Four digits

-Sign E or R or WE or WR

-Three digits

How should the second part of the expression look like? I am trying

```
^([0-9]{4})([E,R,WE,WR]{1})([0-9]{3})$
```

But second part not working.

Answer (score 2):

Use an alternation, not a character class:

```
^([0-9]{4})(E|R|WE|WR)([0-9]{3})$
```

What you currently have says to match any *one* character from the set `{ERW,}`.  But we can simplify your pattern even more:

```
^([0-9]{4})(W?(?:E|R))([0-9]{3})$
```

Answer (score 0):

The `[E,R,WE,WR]{1}` matches 1 occurrence of `E`, `R`, W`or`,`since`[...]` is a [**character class**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) that matches a single char from the set/ranges defined inside the brackets.

You want to make `W` optional with `?` quantifier and then match either `E` or `R`.

You may use

```
^([0-9]{4})(W?[ER])([0-9]{3})$
           ^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/y2nOaN/1).

Here, `W?` matches 1 or 0 occurrences of `W` and `[ER]` character class matches either `E` or `R`.

Note that the fewer alternation groups there are in the pattern, the more efficient the pattern is.